# Nested vlookups in python or pandas

Tags: python, pandas, merge, jupyter

I have 2 data frames, records_df and price_df, their index are the same

price_df:

```
index    product   price/product
 s1        a        34 
 s1        b        34 
 s1        c        23
 s2        a        12
 s2        b        14
 s2        c        65
 s3        a        33
 s3        b        65
 s3        c        54
```

records_df:

```
index    Name   Number  Product     Sum of Amount of Products Day
  s1      x      1234     a               50
  s1      x      1234     a               50
  s1      x      1234     a               50
  s1      x      1234     a               50
  s1      x      1234     a               50
  s2      y      4321     b               30
  s3      z      3219     c               40
  s3      z      3219     d               40
```

what I want to do is to insert the price per product after sum of amount of products per day and merge the two data frames together such that the result would be:

```
index    Name   Number  Product     Sum of Amount of Products Day     Price/product

  s1      x      1234     a               50                              34
  s1      x      1234     a               50                              34 
  s1      x      1234     a               50                              34
  s1      x      1234     a               50                              34
  s2      y      4321     b               30                              34
  s3      z      3219     c               40                              14
  s3      z      3219     b               40                              65
```

I've tried merge and join but it won't work. Basically what I'm trying was sort of a vlookup on the index first and then another vlookup on the product. How do I do a nested vlookup in python?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IIUC, you can just use `loc` with same indexes

```
df2 = df2.set_index(['index', 'Product'])
df = df.set_index(['index', 'product'])
```

Then

```
df2.loc[:, 'price/product'] = df['price/product']

                Name    Number  Sum_of_Amount_of_Products_Day   price/product
index   Product             
s1      a       x       1234    50                              34.0
        a       x       1234    50                              34.0
        a       x       1234    50                              34.0
        a       x       1234    50                              34.0
        a       x       1234    50                              34.0
s2      b       y       4321    30                              14.0
s3      c       z       3219    40                              54.0
        d       z       3219    40                              NaN
```

Comment: Thanks so much!! It works, thought I needed to merge or join to achieve the result.